# Switching between single- and multi-column format

Tags: formatting, two-column

I'm trying to create a pdf for a journal where the authors are in multiple column format but the rest of the document/text is not. How can I get this to work? It auto formats the rest of my document into two columns. I'm exporting it to pdf and I'm using TeXworks.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\title{Article Title}
\author{
    First Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
  \and
    Second Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
    \and
    Third Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
    \and
    Fourth Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This part should be in a single column.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\ldots 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove the `twocolumn` from your first line. Is that what you mean?

Comment: no i want the authors to be multiple columnn , i have 8 in my actual paperfrom all different universities/departments it would take a whole page of just authors if i did it in single colummn , i want the rest of the document to be single column however

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! I've edited your code lightly by removing two spurious lines and by changing the tags. If you haven't already done so, please consider registering with the site so that you can edit your own question (if you desire to do so) and provide comments on answers.

Comment: Please try to write actual sentences in your question. (@Mico: sorry, I might have overwritten your edit.)

Comment: @Caramdir -- no worries. You anticipated my edits perfectly; I just added a couple more to reflect my understanding of the OP's intentions.

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure I agree with you on that reading of the question (and from his answer I think Jake also reads it differently).

Comment: @Mico: The first sentence says "the authors are in multiple column format but the rest of the document/text is not."

Comment: @Caramdir -- you're right. I believe the OP has edited the question in the meantime to clarify its intentions. I'll edit the question again...

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why not just use minipage, like on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#A_practical_example ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The authors of an `article` document are always set in multiple columns, regardless of the `twocolumn` option. Removing `twocolumn` from your document options will yield this result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Article Title}
\author{
    First Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
  \and
    Second Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
    \and
    Third Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
    \and
    Fourth Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu\\
\and
    Fifth Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
  \and
    Sixth Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
    \and
    Seventh Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
    \and
    Eighth Author\\
    Department\\
    school\\
    email@edu
}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
CFD \ldots
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum

\section{future research exc}\label{previous work}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Remark -- This answer is edited radically from the one I posted initially, as the thrust of the OP's question became clear. The first paragraph is, in its contents, identical to Jake's answer.)

Just remove the `twocolumn` option from the `\documentclass` instruction, and the rest of your document will typeset in single-column format. With the code you provide, the `author` block will automatically be typeset in the most space-saving manner possible.

Incidentally, unless all of the paper's authors have different affiliations, you may want to look into using the `authblk` package to simplify references to institutional affiliations shared among some of the contributors.

Comment: thanks for all the help , i also like the lipsum feature